# Serve static content with iis 7.5 from SQL Server 2012 FileTable

Tags: .net, sql, iis-7.5, sql-server-2012, filetable

I'm fighting this problem all day with no success. I have the following configuration:

1. Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
2. SQL Server 2012 Enterprise

I configured the `FILESTREAM` feature and created a filetable. I can access it through the file share and add files. I add a virtual directory pointing to the file share and set it to connect as a user who is windows administrator and database administrator. I also set this user to be used for anonymous access and for the web site's application pool. I am able to access all folders and files in the file share through IIS Management console but whenever I try to browse something in the browser I receive 404 error.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: What are the static file types you are trying?